# Convert Expression<Func<T, U>> to Expression<Func<object, object>>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I have a `LambdaExpression` which is of type `Expression<Func<T, string>>`. The design of the code currently does not allow me to keep `T` which means that I am forced to use the slower `DynamicInvoke` instead of `Invoke`.

Since I know the type of `T` I want to convert the expression so that it accepts a `T` object, allowing me to use `Invoke`. How?

**Here's a good start**

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public string MyProperty => "Foo";
    }

    static LambdaExpression GetExpression(Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> expr)
    {
        return expr;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var e1 = GetExpression(t => t.MyProperty);
        var e2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(e1, e1.Parameters);

        object myClass = new MyClass();
        string s1 = (string)e1.Compile().DynamicInvoke(myClass);
        object s2 = e2.Compile().Invoke(myClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question does not match your title. Are you looking to convert `Func<T, U>` to `Func<object, object>`, to convert `Func<T, object>` to `Func<object, object>`, or to convert `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`? All three have different answers.

Comment: I can write some code to solve this... Only a problem... Do you want to use these expressions for Entity Framework/LINQ to SQL or do you want to simply compile those expressions? Because changing the `Expression`s to make them `Func<object, object>` could make them incompatible with EF.

Comment: Updated the question. In the end I want to compile the expression to be used as a typed delegate, so that I can use Invoke() instead of DynamicInvoke(). I believe `Expression.Convert` is needed in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The non-expression version would look like

```
Func<object, object> Convert<T>(Func<T, object> f) {
  return o => f((T)o);
}
```

This is what you need to do in the expression version as well. You're right, `Expression.Convert` can do that.

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> e1 = t => t.MyProperty;
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var e2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
    Expression.Invoke(e1, Expression.Convert(p, typeof(MyClass))), p);
```

<sub>Note: as @xanatos rightly notes, for converting e.g. `Expression<Func<T, int>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`, although C# supports an implicit boxing conversion from `int` to `object`, expression trees don't. If this is relevant to the question, another `Expression.Convert` is needed.</sub>

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks!

Comment: @hvd I would add another `Expression.Convert` to object externally to the `Expression.Invoke`, in the case you have a value type (they aren't implicitly boxed)

Comment: @xanatos For `Expression<Func<T, U>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`, that could indeed be necessary For `Expression<Func<T, object>>` to `Expression<Func<object, object>>`, it's not. I thought the `Expression<Func<T, U>>` had been edited out and is not relevant to the question, but I see now it hasn't been edited out. You may be right.

Comment: @hvd Exactly my thoughts.