# Convert Expression<Func<T, bool>> to another Predicate Expression Expression<Func<U, bool>>

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-core, expression-trees, ef-core-5.0

I want to convert One predicate Expression(**Expression<Func<Item, bool>>**) to another Predicate Expression (**Expression<Func<ItemEntity, bool>>**) but after converting I am not able to query through LINQ.
I Already try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387196/convert-expressionfunct-u-to-expressionfuncobject-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035260/convert-expressionfunct1-bool-to-expressionfunct2-bool/65035636#65035636) approach but nothing work properly
can anyone tells me how to do it properly, My approach for this problems.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

public class ItemEntity {
    public int ItemId {set;get;}
    public int ItemParentId {set;get;}
    public int ItemName {set;get;}
}

public class Item {
   public int Id{ set;get;}
   public int ParentId{set;get;}
   public int Name {set;get;}
}

public class Program
{
    
    public static Item Convert(ItemEntity itemChild)
    {
        return new Item()
        {
            Id = itemChild.ItemId,
            ParentId = itemChild.ItemParentId,
            Name = itemChild.ItemName
        };
    }
    
    public async Task<IList<ItemEntity>> SelectAsync(Expression<Func<ItemEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        // using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        // private readonly DbContext _context; // Injected globally by using Service.AddScoped<ItemContext>();
        // return await _context.Set<ItemEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        return await Task.Run(() => new List<ItemEntity>()); // actually return the result with matching predicate
    }
    public async Task<List<Item>> GetItems(Expression<Func<Item, bool>> expression)
    {
        
            MethodInfo convertMethod = ((Func<ItemEntity, Item>)Convert).Method;
            
            var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemEntity));
            var converted = Expression.Lambda<Func<ItemEntity, bool>>(
                Expression.Invoke(expression, Expression.Convert(p, typeof(Item), convertMethod)), p);
            
            IList<ItemEntity> res = await SelectAsync(converted);
            var t = res.Select(x => Convert(x)).ToList();
            return t;
    }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program pr = new Program();
        Func<Expression<Func<Item, bool>>, Task<List<Item>>> getItem = pr.GetItems;
        var res = getItem.Invoke(x => x.Id.Equals(1));
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

but I am getting error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()\r\n    .Where(i => ((Item)i).Id.Equals(__Id_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I don't able to understand it properly, as per my understanding I am using ToList() for client evaluation, but and also provide method to convert ItemEntity to Item.

I any other way to create fresh Expression Tree based on ItemEntity and then query on DBSet?
Any Help is appreciated

version used:

- dot-net 5.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.6
- EntityFramework 6.4.4
- Database SQL Server

Comment: Are you inventing another Generic Repository?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv no not at all, here I am giving you the sample code, the requirement is that my business logic is play around with Item class and ItemEntity class represent SQL server database table, when try to do LINQ on list of Item objects I want that predicate expression to be translated to the predicate expression based on parameter ItemEntity to get the data from database, in my code all repository on seperate dll

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach. Main idea to use filter exactly on the projected DTO before materialization.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ItemEntity
{
    public int ItemId { set; get; }
    public int ItemParentId { set; get; }
    public int ItemName { set; get; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public int ParentId { set; get; }
    public int Name { set; get; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static Expression<Func<ItemEntity, Item>> ToItem()
    {
        return itemChild => new Item
        {
            Id = itemChild.ItemId,
            ParentId = itemChild.ItemParentId,
            Name = itemChild.ItemName
        };
    }

    public Task<IList<Item>> SelectAsync(Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.Set<ItemEntity>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(ToItem())
            .Where(predicate)
            .ToListAsync();

        //return Task.Run(() => new List<ItemEntity>().AsQueryable().Select(ToItem()).Where(predicate).ToList());
    }

    public async Task<IList<Item>> GetItems(Expression<Func<Item, bool>> expression)
    {
        var res = await SelectAsync(expression);
        return res;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var pr = new Program();
        var res = pr.GetItems(x => x.Id == 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me the solution but there is small problem here, first _context.Set<ItemEntity>() return an IQuerable and you first make projection and then make selection, if I do this then I have to force client side evaluation by using AsIEnumerable or ToList or TOListAsync() which is not an optimum approach, that's why I want to cast Expression<Func<Item, bool>> to Expression<Func<ItemEntity, bool>> in that case it can make query to server side

Comment: and second ToItem() is in different dll and SelectAsync is in different dll and I don't want to create any back dependency in Repository dll

Comment: Will correct answer later today. But I think problem here as usual - dumb generic repository pattern.